# Change Zope2 browser resourceDirectory permission to allow only Authenticated users

Tags: security, browser, zope, zope.component

I have a `browser:resourceDirectory` setup in Zope2 and I have: `permission="zope2.Public"`.

what should be changed in order to allow only "Authenticated" users access to the resource directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by creating a new permission `my_permission` and mapped the permission to `Authenticated` role. Then adding the permission to resourceDirectory like `permission="my_permission"`

Permission:

```
<permission
      id="my_permission"
      title="my_permission"
      description="My Permission">
    <role name="Authenticated"/>
</permission>
```

resourceDirectory:

```
 <browser:MyDirectory
    name="static_contents"
    directory="myfolder"
    permission="my_permission"
    />
```